# How to map object of one class to another class with EF code first TPH

Tags: c#, entity-framework, tph

**Scenario**

I have e.g. abstract class called *Quiz* and two children of this Quiz: *SingleAnswerQuiz* and *MultipleAnswerQuiz*. I map this model into Table per hierarchy with entity framework.

**Problem**

Is there any way to change one SingleAnswerQuiz type to MultipleAnswerQuiz? I do not want to delete single quiz and create multiple with data of deleted quiz. I want to have the same id after "mapping". Should I use Discriminator?

Comment: Can you provide the code defining the objects?

Comment: it is not necessary, it is just kind of proof of concept